# iMacros Extract DATA from Input Text

Tags: imacros, data-extraction

I want to extract data from an input Text through iMacros. Here is my code:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=NAME:timeentry_total CONTENT=60
```

I tried using:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=NAME:timeentry_total EXTRACT:TXT
```

This gives me 'wrong format' error.

What should I do?

Thanks
Fahad

Answer (score 1):

Please change the format to

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=NAME:timeentry_total EXTRACT=TXT
```

Instead of

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=NAME:timeentry_total EXTRACT:TXT
```

As you can see, the only difference is that you are using `:` instead of `=` which is causing the issue!

Comment: Yep indeed, ah-ah...!